# What is the best way to add conditional style with styled-components & styled-system?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to create a button component with styled-system and styled-components.

The variants of styled-system works great, but I am wondering how to add conditional css. For example, I am trying to render primary block button.

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  ${props => props.block && css`width: 100%;`
`;

// primary
<StyledButton block variant="primary" />
```

This works as expected, but I would like to know if there is any better way to apply `block` in beautiful way with pure javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can shorten your specific example as follows (you don't need to use `css` method there):

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  ${({block}) => block && 'width: 100%;'}
`;
```

But generally, I believe this is the only way of doing it. Doesn't really look ugly to me, but if you have some complex conditions you can probably move some code into separate variables or functions with descriptive names.

Comment: this is technically the same as the solution i shared. I'd rather use classnames and apply it to make it more in js fashion..

Answer (score 2):

You can create a mixin and add it conditionally. You just need to import css from **Styled-components**. For example:

```
const buttonWidthMixin = css`
   width: 100%
`
```

Then you can add it to the button like so:

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
   ${props => props.block && buttonWidthMixin};
`
```

Now if you add block prop to the button it will add our new mixin to css.

Comment: Did you forgot to add } after `buttonWidthMixin`?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to return styles as json object this way:

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  ${({block}) => block && {width: '100%'}}
`;
```